# Functions with different signature, but the compiler calls the wrong one

Tags: c#, function

I have two functions:

```
partial class Database
{
    public void Insert(string table, params string[] values)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO [{0}] VALUES ('{1}')";
        ExecuteNonQuery(string.Format(query, table, string.Join("','", values)));
    }

    public string Insert(string table, string returnedColumn, params string[] values)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO [{0}] OUTPUT INSERTED.{1} VALUES ('{2}')";
        return ExecuteScalar(string.Format(query, table, returnedColumn, string.Join("','", values))).ToString();
    }
}
```

Both of them are executing an `INSERT` on a table in the database. The difference is that while the first one only inserts the data into the database, the second also returns a value from one of the columns in the inserted row, using the `OUTPUT` keyword in SQL.

The problem is that when I am trying to call the first function, the compiler calls the second one. So, for example, if I have this code:

```
Database DB = new Database();
DB.Insert("tableName", "some data");
```

Visual studio actually treats it as if I called the second function:
[image]

What is the problem and how can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: `DB.Insert("tableName", new[]{"some data"});`

Comment: The problem is that you are calling Insert(string, string), because params is optional. Your compiler basically thinks it should pick the second one because it matches more closely.

Comment: I'm not sure if you read the same C# spec as I did, but that's the correct overload to call. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @Blackunknown - You are right. The problem is that `params` is optional. So I would have to take it as an answer.

Comment: I think you should be giving those methods different names, since they are doing different things.

Comment: I will consider that. But I like thing simple, so if you want to insert stuff, you call `insert` - and then you can read the documentation, so you use the right overload. But I guess it's just a matter of programming style. Thank you very much everyone!

Comment: I would really advice you to listen to @MatthewWatson. As I also added in the answer. Your choice of course :)

Comment: The chance of someone accidentally calling the wrong method is extremely high if you leave it like it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call it by using **named parameter**

```
        Database d = new Database();

        //ExecuteScalar
        d.Insert(table: "demoTabele", returnedColumn: "returnedColumn",values: new string[]{"rest arguments1", "rest arguments2"});

        //ExecuteNonQuery
        d.Insert(table: "demoTabele", values: new string[] { "rest arguments1", "rest arguments2" });
```

Comment: This is an awesome answer. I really do not know if choosing it or @Lee's answer. Both are GREAT solutions.

Comment: This is the best and most relevant answer, I shouldn't be renaming my function just because it overloads the previous one

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap your second argument in an array which will force the overload you want to be chosen:

```
DB.Insert("tableName", new[] { "some data" });
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are calling Insert(string, string), because params is optional. Your compiler basically thinks it should pick the second one because it matches more closely.

My first instinct would be to name the methods differently. Seeing as a method called Insert should do what it says: insert stuff. If it returns something I would like to know what that resembles before I call the function. Of course I can read the 2nd parameter and know what it returns.